# Discord Bot with API google sheets

Tags: python, api, google-sheets, discord, bots

I'm trying to make a connect discordbot-googlesheetsAPI for my bot write in one sheet, but the error occurs

```
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

and in the discord bot this error occurs

```
<HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/14G_gnMDmu7Y2AL9LLSyPFZgRr2uN9s7uVrZUKfKlbyI/values/DATA_2%21A1%3AG42?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED&alt=json returned "Unable to parse range: DATA_2!A1:G42". Details: "Unable to parse range: DATA_2!A1:G42">
```

btw i'm sending my code, help me pls

```
{
  "PREFIX": "-",
  "DISCORD_KEY": "**************************************************",
  "GOOGLE_KEY": "AIzaSyDIOqNx6****************sE",
  "SHEET_ID": "14G_gnMDmu7Y2AL9LLSyPFZgRr2uN9s7uV*****",
  "UPDATE_DELAY": 3000,
  "DISCORD_DELAY": 300,
  "SIMUL_UPDATE_INTERVAL": 3600,
  "UPDATE_LINK": "https://reaperscans.com.br/",
  "SUBMISSION_CHANNEL": "880292483056168980",
  "UPDATE_CHANNELS": [
    "880899763489349642"
  ],
  "TEST_CHANNELS": [
    "880305943580143630",
    "880305969928744960"
  ],
  "ADMINS": [
    "461050292473954305",
    "223545327611936778",
    "345938621137944577",
    "423547318222979072"
  ]
}
```

**OBS**: The API knows that i'm calling it, but always this error stopped me

Comment: I've tried everything to find a valid API key

Comment: Now the error is Erro 400: redirect_uri_mismatch, but the localhost every time changes when I restart the bot, soo i don't know what i should do now!

Comment: If there are other problems than the error you get, please improve your question and provide some code that we can analyze, keeping in mind how to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

From what you posted here, it would appear to be only an invalid API key. It seems that the discord side is fine, but it retrieve a `400` when trying to parse something (`"Unable to parse range: DATA_2!A1:G42"`), probably, 'cause when trying to interface with google it returns a `403` caused by an invalid key.

Be sure to limit the key that you're using with the correct APIs

Comment: yes, my API recieve the request bot always this error occurs, i've tried a lot of keys in my API, but all of then fail
i'm trying add localhost:number in perms, but always the port change, soo i don't know what i've should do now...
https://prnt.sc/1qubfni

Comment: I'm afraid I'm having trouble understanding what you're saying. Are you testing multiple keys? Do you mean that you're creating more keys via the google cloud platform? Also, where are you changing the port?

Comment: I've tested some keys trying to find the problem, but always tjis error occurs, soo I'm just using one key(API key). btw, i'm not changing de the port, when i restart de discord bot the port changes ex: localhost:77777 to localgost:75686

Comment: Please, update your question with the code that's causing problems and try to be clearer, I can't tell what problem you are encountering

Comment: Also, I still don't understand what keys you are changing, you should use one key after that you limited it.